# Will Windows Reset PC remove windows update and/or drivers?

Tags: windows, drivers, updates, reset

My PC is running a little slow so I wanted to Reset using the Windows 10 reset feature. Will doing this remove Windows updates or drivers I've installed up to that point?

Comment: Reset feature installs Windows, if you choose to keep personal files, files within your profile folder will be saved.  Drivers are not kept.

Comment: Use Double Driver to backup your existing drivers onto a USB stick. Once you've reinstalled, you can point Device Manager at the USB stick and it'll re-install the drivers which are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your PC which does the following.

**Reset PC**

> All of your Personal Files and Apps will be removed
>
> Your PC settings will be changed back to default

You will have to re-install all of your programs & third party drivers again.
It rolls the computer back to it's factory settings, so Any updates will also be removed and you will have to manually install them again.

But for some alternative solutions before you reset i'd recommend running a malware / anti-virus scan first.
A lot of "slow computer" issues can be resolved by unwanted Malware or Virusses or a messed up registry.

**Malware Bytes** - Remove Malware
https://www.malwarebytes.com/

**AVG Free** - Remove Viruses
http://free.avg.com/ie-en/homepage

**CCleaner** - Clean your Registry
https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download

Both programs are free, i'd run these along side CCleaner before resetting your PC to default settings as it could improve the situation without going through the hassle of losing everything.

If your computer is clean and still slow, i'd try a refresh as well.

**Refresh:**

> When you Refresh your PC:
>
> Windows will save your personal files, personalization settings, and Modern apps installed from the Windows Store.
>
> Windows will reset your PC settings.
>
> Windows will remove all installed desktop programs. A list of the removed programs will be saved to your desktop.

If neither of the above worked then I would go ahead with the reset.

If after the reset your computer is still sluggish you could try adding more RAM.

Comment: Or you could consider adding more RAM 1st.

Comment: The first mentioned are all free and don't require much time, if they solve the issue then money saved no?

Comment: Thanks guys. Just one confusion will "Refresh" also removes the updates?

Comment: Of course it will.  What happens with a Reset are well documented.  There is no "Refresh" in Windows 10