# Will my Windows version and all Windows updates remain same after Windows 10 Reset

Tags: windows, windows-10, reset

I want to reset my Dell Laptop using reset this PC and remove everything(all files and personal data removed).

Why I am doing so? It's because I have a problem with [visual studio installer that is listed here](https://superuser.com/questions/1687273/cannot-install-visual-studio-installer-vs-community-exe-and-always-run-into-dl?noredirect=1#comment2592508_1687273).

If anyone could solve that problem, then maybe I don't need to reset. But let's just stick to the question.

I wanted to ask if the following will remain or get removed too?

1. Windows Version

   I have Windows 10 21H1 right now and when my Laptop came, it had Windows 1909 I think. If I reset my PC and choose **remove everything**, will I be switched back to Windows 10 version 1909 or stick to 21H1?

Also, I am getting a notification that I can update to Windows 11. Will I be able to do it after the reset or I will have to go through all the updates to get to Windows 11?

2. GPU drivers

   Will my GPU drivers still be installed or removed along with everything on PC? I am talking about both internal GPU (Intel integrated 630) and Nvidia GTX 1650.
3. Dell Drivers and Applications

   Will my laptop drivers and Applications like Dell Support Assist and Alienware Command Centre remain in my Laptop after reset or removed?

I have gone through the [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1092203/will-windows-reset-pc-remove-windows-update-and-or-drivers) but didn't find my answer.

I need suggestion on whether to upgrade to Windows 11 and then reset or reset it now? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have windows 10 21H1 right now and when my Laptop came, it had
> windows 1909 I think. So if I reset my PC and choose remove
> everything, will I be switched back to windows 10 version 1909 or
> stick to 21H1?

If you choose Reset and Remove Everything you should end up with the same version of Windows. You can quickly update Windows.

> Also, I am getting a notification that I can update to windows 11.
> Will I be able to do it after the reset or I will have to go through
> all the updates to get to windows 11?

Yes. Starting fresh as per the first comment here does not affect the ability to upgrade to Windows 11.

> GPU drivers
>
> Will my GPU drivers still be installed or removed along with
> everything on PC? i am talking about both internal Gpu (intel
> integrated 630) and Nvidia GTX 1650.
>
> Dell Drivers and Applications

> Will my laptop drivers and Applications like Dell Support Assist and
> Alienware Command Centre remain in my Laptop after reset or removed?

This depends on the Drivers in the Microsoft Driver Catalogue.  If the drivers are there, they will be reinstalled. If not, you can install them again.

Since you are doing a fresh install of Windows 10, resolve driver issues right away before installing anything else.

Overall, what you suggest and wish to do will work.

Comment: Thankyou so much, reinstalled just after you confirmed and it turned out to be good.

Comment: Thanks for the update